# executing two queries in firebase and finding the difference of the two

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

My Firebase has two children

- expenditure
- sales

I want to find the difference between sales and expenditure.

Currently i am able to find the total of both children.

However i am stuck trying to find the difference between the two.

Below is the code I have executed to compute the sum.

```
    dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


    DatabaseReference dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    dref= dref.child("LukenyaExpenditure");

    dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            int totalAmount = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                DogExpenditure dogExpenditure = postSnapshot.getValue(DogExpenditure.class);
                totalAmount += dogExpenditure.getAmount();
            }


            textView4.setText("Your total expenses for Lukenya Unit is:" +Integer.toString(totalAmount));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }


        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: post screen shot of your database.

Comment: @TheManHasNoName i have edited the question